# What is the best way to mount a component when you need a prop from another one

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

I have two actions. Sometimes the value returns `undefined` so instead of receiving the users post I receive all the post. I need to find a better way to get my functions to work together.

Right now I have:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchUser();
    let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));
    console.log(userId)
    this.props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId);
}
```

Because it can't get the `userId` right away so it won't add the parameter to the end of my user search so it gives me all post.

If I try to do something else like:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchUser();
}
componentWillReceiveProps(){
  let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));
  console.log(userId)
  this.props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId);

}
```

It will loop give me the post but loop infinitly in the console.

Also putting the code below in the render will also make it loop forever.

```
let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));
console.log(userId)
this.props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId);
```

What is the best way to go about this so it works how I want it to.

**EDIT**

```
export const fetchUser = () => dispatch => {
    Promise.all([fetch('http://10.6.254.22:5000/userinformation/3')])

    .then(([res1]) => { 
       return Promise.all([res1.json()]) 
    })
    .then(([user]) => dispatch ({
      // set state in here
        type: FETCH_USER,
        payload: user
    //   console.log(res1)
    //   this.setState({ results: res1, posts: res2 })
      // this.setState({ posts: res2 })
    }));
}
```

Comment: You need componentDidUpdate hook instead of componentDidMount.

Comment: Doesnt work it still loops. and makes the component re render infinitly

Comment: Well, is `fetchUser()` asynchronous? Sounds like it is, in which case you should have it return a promise or take a callback function or have some way of indicating the method has completed. Also, just as a naming convention, I would be very surprised to come across code like `this.props.user.map(...)`, since "user" is a singular noun, but `map` is used on arrays...

Comment: I updated it, how would i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fetch posts 1 time, but can't do it on mount because you don't have the userId yet. If you do it in `componentWillReceiveProps` you get an infinite loop -- because fetching posts updates props.

You need to run some code when the component updates, but only when you have a user id and didn't previously have a user id. `componentWillReceiveProps` is discouraged and deprecated so we will use `componentDidUpdate` which gets `prevProps` as it's first paramater.

Using *componentDidUpdate*:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  let prevUserId = prevProps.user.map((user) => (user.id));
  let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));
  if(!prevUserId && userId) {
    this.props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId);
  }
}
```

If you're curious how this might look using hooks, here's an example:

```
const userId = props.user.map((user) => (user.id))

React.useEffect(() => {
  if(userId) {
    props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId)
  }
}, [userId])
```

The hook will only be called when `userId` has changed value, and will only fetch posts if there is a userId